# Unable to create relationship 'FK_PATIENTS_VICTIMS'

Tags: mysql

MySQL says:

> the alter table statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PATIENTS_VICTIMS". The conflict occurred in the database " my_database", table "dbo.victims", column "victim_id'.

I tried to alter the table by inputting;

```
ALTER TABLE PATIENTS WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PATIENTS_VICTIMS] FOREIGN KEY(VICTIM_ID) REFERENCES VICTIM(ID)
```

Patients table

```
create table patients(
    victim_id int(4),
    blood_type varchar(4),
    vaccinations varchar(100),
    assigned_practitioner int(10),
    hospital_id int(10),
    insurance_id int(10),
    symptoms varchar(200);
```

Victims table

```
create table victims(
    victim_id int(4) primary key,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    sex char(1) constraint persons_sex_ck check(sex IN('F','M')),
    PHONE_NUMBER varchar(20),
    DOB varchar(13),
    address varchar(30),
    city varchar(20),
    zip int(5),
    state varchar(5)
);
```

Comment: Check if you have values in `patients.victim_id` that would violate the new constraint: NULL values or values that to not exist in `victim.id`. Make sure both columns are of the same type.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table PATIENTS` and `show create table VICTIM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
REFERENCES VICTIM(ID)
```

You need:

```
REFERENCES VICTIMS(Victim_ID)
```